# Sporadic and Exceptional

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, monster

I have been reading this recent paper of J.McKay and YH. He (they've written a number of papers recently, including a fun and joking one on 42 which overflow commented on) called  "Sporadic and Exceptional"

http://arxiv.org/abs/1505.06742

There are some old ideas which are summarized and some new observations and numerology.  Whatever it is, it seems like some kind of over-arching set of correspondences linking Monster/Baby/Fischer versus E8/E7/E6, i.e., the largest sporadic groups versus the largest simple exceptional Lie algebras, using cusp numbers and enumerative problems on del Pezzo surfaces.

However, numerology aside. Anyone have any ideas/comments on how to find the geometric significance of the cusps and why they are relevant to Moonshine and to this current context?

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/296487/